# Perl curses: refresh() doesnt delete lines

Tags: perl, ncurses, curses

```
sub display {
    my @data = @_;
    my $max_row = 0;
    my $max_col = 0;
    getmaxyx($max_row, $max_col);
    clear();                        <------ i dont want to clear everytime

    if ($start_display) {
        my $row   = 0;
        my $color = COLOR_PAIR(1);
        attron($color);

        attroff($color);
        foreach my $line (@data) {
            $color = COLOR_PAIR(1);
            $color = COLOR_PAIR(2) if ($line =~ /waiting/);
            attron($color);
            $line = substr($line, 0, $max_col);
            addstr($row++, 0, $line);
            attroff($color);
            last if ($row >= $max_row - 1);
        }
        $color = COLOR_PAIR(1);
        attron($color);
        attroff($color);
    } else {
        my $dots = '.';
        $dots = $dots x $dot_cnt;
        addstr("Program is starting...$dots");
        $dot_cnt++;
        sleep 1;
    }

    my $color = COLOR_PAIR(1);
    attron($color);
    addstr($max_row-1, 0, $usage);
    attroff($color);

    refresh();     <------ refreshes but doesnt clear 
} ## end sub display
```

Right now, i am clearing the screen everytime but this is making the screen very choppy. If i get rid of `clear()` the chopiness goes away but `refresh()` does not update correctly (i.e. leaves the previously displayed lines as is when some should get deleted)

How do I update the screen properly so that only the changed lines get updated and delete the lines from the screen properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`addstr()` will only write through to the length of the string passed to it. In order to avoid remnants, you need to ensure that the string is padded to the width of the window. I would suggest padding the string with spaces in the step where you truncate to `$max_col`:

```
$line = substr( $line . " " x $max_col, 0, $max_col );
```

Or factor it out:

```
sub addstr_pad { 
    my ( $row, $str, $width ) = @_;
    addstr( $row, 0, substr( $str . " " x $width, 0, $width ) ); 
}
...
addstr_pad( $row++, $line, $max_col );
```

To ensure that you're clearing any rows that may have had text from the last iteration, include this after iterating over `@data`:

```
while( $row <= $max_row ) { 
    addstr( $row++, 0, " " x $max_col )); 
}
```

You wouldn't necessarily need to clear through `$max_row` if the length of `@data` were retained from the previous run.

Comment: Thanks. it works but also i had to write blank lines until $max_row (not just $mat_col) as well to erase those.

Comment: Right, but that is the beauty of curses - it makes it easy to update a portion of the screen without clearing the rest. Glad I got you in the right direction.